# Align columns in ASCII file

Tags: text-processing, editors, columns, ascii

I have a text file that looks like his:

```
#c1     c2              c3              c4              c5              c6      c7      c8      c9      c10     c11     c12     c13
4599    995,274 2523,658        264,1417170     -33,6000        -0,3600 0,0202  0,0069  0,0227  10,1041 0,0169  0,2817  0,0239
6173    1552,290        1595,696        264,0603912     -33,4880        0,4374  0,0287  1,8123  0,0385  10,1289 0,0292  2,8445  0,0366
6456    1658,630        1529,292        264,0449377     -33,4800        0,0109  0,0234  1,0955  0,0296  10,5032 0,0223  1,7168  0,0293
8932    2750,029        1374,395        263,8866195     -33,4615        -0,3185 0,0249  0,9196  0,0302  10,5858 0,0221  1,3886  0,0296
4095    820,716 495,315 264,1658451     -33,3546        -0,4388 0,0216  0,6497  0,0252  10,6026 0,0188  1,1796  0,0258
4737    1045,289        1395,983        264,1338240     -33,4636        0,5900  0,0231  0,8853  0,0273  10,6501 0,0204  1,1661  0,0270
```

ie: not aligned at certain random lines (the file is ~10000 lines long) I need it to look like this:

```
#c1     c2              c3              c4              c5              c6      c7      c8      c9      c10     c11     c12     c13
4599    995,274         2523,658        264,1417170     -33,6000        -0,3600 0,0202  0,0069  0,0227  10,1041 0,0169  0,2817  0,0239
6173    1552,290        1595,696        264,0603912     -33,4880        0,4374  0,0287  1,8123  0,0385  10,1289 0,0292  2,8445  0,0366
6456    1658,630        1529,292        264,0449377     -33,4800        0,0109  0,0234  1,0955  0,0296  10,5032 0,0223  1,7168  0,0293
8932    2750,029        1374,395        263,8866195     -33,4615        -0,3185 0,0249  0,9196  0,0302  10,5858 0,0221  1,3886  0,0296
4095    820,716         495,315         264,1658451     -33,3546        -0,4388 0,0216  0,6497  0,0252  10,6026 0,0188  1,1796  0,0258
4737    1045,289        1395,983        264,1338240     -33,4636        0,5900  0,0231  0,8853  0,0273  10,6501 0,0204  1,1661  0,0270
```

So basically I'm looking for a script/command line utility to automatically align the columns of the file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try doing this in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

To test on `STDOUT` :

```
column -t file.txt
```

To modify the file :

```
column -t file.txt > new_file.txt && mv new_file.txt file.txt
```

As you can see, that's all you need. It saves you a lot of time playing with complicated `printf` tricks.

Comment: This command did nothing, it merely displayed the file in the terminal and ended. What am I missing here?

Comment: Which OS are you using ? (put it in your original POST)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Just tried it again, nothing. Should that command be modifying the original file or creating a new aligned one?

Comment: See my edit to edit the file inplace (my previous version was just to display in a terminal)

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the aptly named column tool.

For what you want you have to pipe your data to column like this

```
cat yourfile | column -s " " -t
```

Define the delimiter with -s

```
-s " "
```

Tell colume to make a table with -t