# Bad columns formatting by the tr command

Tags: tr, tabs

I have a file like this

```
AAA:111111:FIRSTLINE
BBBBBBB:22222222222:SECONDLINE
CCC:33333333333333333333:THIRD LINE
```

And I wanted to change each ":" by a tab. For that, I used the tr command

```
tr ":" "\t"
```

But I got this

```
ABC     12345   FIRSTLINE
DEFGH   1112232 SECONDLINE
IJK     77623786487261  THIRD LINE
```

I want to make the words in the third column all starting in the same place, but it seems that when a word in the previous column is too long, the word from the next column moves much foward than I want. Is there a quick way of solving this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Align columns in ASCII file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65370/align-columns-in-ascii-file) Attention to the second answer that explains how to use a custom delimiter, in your case, `:`.

Comment: Another solution would be to use `expand` with specific tab settings.  `cat file.txt | tr : '\t' | expand -t9,31`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ cat ex
AAA:111111:FIRSTLINE
BBBBBBB:22222222222:SECONDLINE
CCC:33333333333333333333:THIRD LINE

$ column --table --separator ':' ex
AAA      111111                FIRSTLINE
BBBBBBB  22222222222           SECONDLINE
CCC      33333333333333333333  THIRD LINE
```

The `column` command generates a table with the given separator.

Comment: Or `column -t -s ':'` to be portable to other systems with non-GNU variants of `column`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `tr` can solve it, but `awk` is great at solving problems like that.

The `printf` command in `awk` works very similar to in `C`.  The minus sign in the format string `%-8s` makes the output left-justified.

The switch `-F:` sets the field separator to `:`, which causes awk variabels `$1`, `$2` and `$3` to be set to the text separated by that separators.  Be sure to use single quotes on the command line so `bash` doesn't try to interpret them.

```
awk -F: '{printf "%-8s %-21s %s\n",$1,$2,$3}' file.txt
```

With your input file, I got this output:

```
AAA      111111                FIRSTLINE
BBBBBBB  22222222222           SECONDLINE
CCC      33333333333333333333  THIRD LINE
```

Comment: The fixed lengths will cut of strings that are too long. One would have to define with the longest strings in each column to exclude that.

Comment: This is a concept demonstration, @FelixJN.  In some contexts the user knows his maximum field widths, so this would be perfect.  Also, if columns automatically adjust to fit the data, one malformed line could cause the first or second column to be wider than the page, which would destroy the intent.